# Ffmeg to convert images to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have this kind of named files, as shown in the image. How can i use ffmpeg to make apple pro res video out of them.
[image]

i do not know what to try

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The laziest way I could think of doing this in a Unix-compatible system with an up-to-date version of ffmpeg is:

> `cat *jpg | ffmpeg -i - video.mkv`

This assumes that the names of the JPEG images are already sorted by time (earliest to latest).